# Dim background when video is played

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the html5 video element a lot more now. I'd like to dim the background of my page when the user presses play on the video. When they press Pause or video ends, I want the screen to turn off the dim.

I have this div on my page that is set to `display: none` It is not visible on the page when it loads but I'm not familiar enough with Javascript to get it to do what I want.

Here is the div on my page that sets the dim.

```
<div id="overlay" style="display:none;position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;opacity:0.6;"></div>
```

Video HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="introRight">
        <video poster="img/WhoWeAre.jpg" preload="auto" controls>
        <source src="video/WhoWeAre_HI.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
        <source src="video/WhoWeAre_HI.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
        <source src="video/WhoWeAre_HI.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
        </video>
    </div> <!-- end introRight -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('video').on('play', function(e) {
   $("#overlay").show();
}, true);

$('video').on('pause', function(e) {
 $("#overlay").hide();
}, true);

$('video').on('ended', function() {
  $("#overlay").hide();
});
```

Maybe something like what is outlined above?

Answer (score 1):

You can test:

```
$("video").on('play',function(){
    $("#overlay").show();
});

$("video").on('pause',function(){
    $("#overlay").hide();
});

$("video").on('ended',function(){
    $("#overlay").hide();
});
```

But you have to add a background-color for the #overlay to dim the background. Morover you can set a z-index for the overlay which is lower than the video to be sure the video is always on top:

```
#overlay{
   background-color: #000;
   z-index: 0;
}
#video{
   z-index: 999
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ptvsovw7/3/

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to identify the [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) you are going to need.  It seems that `playing` and `suspend` are what you are looking for.

Second, during playback, you'll want to set your background as appropriate... assuming you are only needing to set the background for the body:

```
function dimBackground() {
  //dim background, alternatively, you can add a className
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#333';
}

function undimBackground() {
  // remove assigned property, fallback to stylesheet
  delete document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor;
}
```

From here, you can create event listeners for the media player on your page...

```
var player = document.getElementById('MyVideoElementId');
// or
var player = document.querySelector('.MyContainer video');

//subscribe to events
player.addEventListener('playing', dimBackground);
player.addEventListener('suspend', undimBackground);
```

---

NOTE: This will only work for modern browsers using the `<video>` element.  Older browsers don't support this, and the events will be different for fallback players.  `addEventListener` requires `IE9` or newer browsers, all modern browsers support this.